# Seekable MP3 with PHP in jPlayer

Tags: php, http-headers, mp3, fopen, jplayer

My question is simply: how can I output an mp3 with PHP that is seekable? I believe I have the appropriate headers set and I have tried with both readfile() and fopen() because my research has led me to believe that readfile() does not support byteranges and fopen() does. However, I really don't understand how to work with or set byteranges, just that I apparently need to. I am playing the song through jPlayer and the song plays fine, but it not seekable. In other words, you can't skip through the song by clicking different places on the seek bar.

Here is the code that is outputting the mp3 file:

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . $file . ";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
//readfile("$path");
$music = fopen($path, 'r');
fseek($music, 0);
fpassthru($music);
exit();
```

If I need to read the Range header, how do I do that?

Comment: Have you solved ? This question was interesting !

Comment: No not really. I haven't marked it as solved because I just went ahead and used a direct link to the mp3 file. I also discovered that Safari on Mac is able to seek, but Chrome on Mac and Safari and Chrome on iOS doesn't work. What's especially interesting is that mp3 files served up by PHP on iOS is treated as a live streaming file and the audio.duration tag is set to infinity.

Comment: MP3 isn't technically seekable on its own unless you use it within a seekable container.  MPEG streams don't have nice pointers, nor guaranteed frame offsets.  Most software that uses MP3 will "needle drop" at a guessed point based on the file length, average bitrate, and desired spot in the stream.  It will then decode from this spot.  The only way to guarantee a location is to decode the entire stream up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent days trying to solve the same thing.  I'm yet to crack it, but I have noticed this.

Mp3s aren't skipping ahead (due to quicktime grabbing the first byte then going back to the rest)
soundcloud streams (which are mp3) however, are letting me skip ahead (when played through the same player)

I suspect you might find the solution in the the soundcloud headers (since they somehow cracked it).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refrain from posting answers  that don't answer the question. When you have enough rep you will be able to post comments.